# Blocking collections + Multiple Worker threads per blocking collection + Wait For Work Completion

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

I have to do action in batch of 1000 message say Action A, B, C. I can do these actions in parallel.
I created groups for them. To increase parallelism, I created subgroups with in each group. Task with in a subgroup needs to be executed serially. But two subgroups can execute in parallel.
After a batch of 1000 finishes, I have to do some processing ie save in db. But I am unable to understand , how to wait for all the task to finish (I am not interested in waiting in middle just at the end of 1000 taks). Any suggestions are welcome.

```
public class OrderlyThreadPool<t> : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<t> _workingqueue = null;
    Action<t> _handler = null;
    public OrderlyThreadPool(int wrkerCount, Action<t> handler)
    {
        _workingqueue = new BlockingCollection<t>();
        _handler = handler;
        Worker worker = new Worker(wrkerCount, Process); //WorkerCount is always 1
        worker.Start();
    }

    public void AddItem(t item)
    {
        _workingqueue.Add(item);
    }
    private void Process()
    {
        foreach (t item in _workingqueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            _handler(item);
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _workingqueue.CompleteAdding();
        _workingqueue = null;
    }

}

public class Worker
{
    int _wrkerCount = 0;
    Action _action = null;
    public Worker(int workerCount, Action action)
    {
        _wrkerCount = workerCount;
        _action = action;

    }
    public void Start()
    {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < _wrkerCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(_action);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I will create OrderlyThreadPool for each subgroup.
I am recv messages from say source, which blocks if no message is available. So my code, looks like

```
while(true)
{

    var message = GetMsg();

    foreach(OrderlyThreadPool<Msg> a in myList)
    {
        a.AddMsg(message);

    }

    if(msgCount > 1000)
    {
    Wait for all threads to finish work;

    }
    else
    {
    msgCount =msgCount+1;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You start your tasks but you don't keep a reference. Simply store these tasks, expose them through the Worker and OrderlyThreadPool and use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all of them to complete:

```
public class Worker
{
    //...
    List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
    public Task Completion { get { return Task.WhenAll(_tasks); } }
    public void Start()
    {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < _wrkerCount; i++)
        {
            Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(_action));
        }
    }
}

public class OrderlyThreadPool<t> : IDisposable
{
    //...
    public Task Completion { get { return _worker.Completion; }}
}
```

```
await Task.WhenAll(myList.Select(orderlyThreadPool => orderlyThreadPool.Completion));
```

---

However, you should probably consider using TPL Dataflow instead. It's an actor-based framework that encapsulates completion, batching, concurrency levels and so forth...

Comment: Hello, My sitchuation, say I have just 6 members in myList.So for 1 message  6 task will be executing. I want to know when all the task have executed 1000 times. ie 1000 messages have been processed. So I dont know how can I do that, any suggestion